# Is that possible to do git clone inside container , instead of UI. I am having multiple users which want to use single vscode container

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am having multiple users which are going to use same openserver vscode container to open different types of repo . i dont want to use vscode web ui to redirect access for github

I have spinned a docker container given here https://hub.docker.com/r/gitpod/openvscode-server
I am running it on ecs service.